# TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web

Here is my index.html file code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="order_system">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>order_system</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="splash/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.5/fire-messaging.js"></script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/flutter_service_worker.js");
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script>
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyBcp4nLrdafciehE8r6ajHkwMhON9cLjJs",
        authDomain: "order-system-623aa.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://order-system-623aa.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "order-system-623aa",
        storageBucket: "order-system-623aa.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "34260933778",
        appId: "1:34260933778:web:4ea612571d33e7b27c5a4b",
        measurementId: "G-C798KHHTXK",
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/8.4.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
       https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/8.4.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Firebase -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <picture id="splash">
    <source srcset="splash/img/light-1x.png 1x, splash/img/light-2x.png 2x, splash/img/light-3x.png 3x" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light) or (prefers-color-scheme: no-preference)">
    <source srcset="splash/img/dark-1x.png 1x, splash/img/dark-2x.png 2x, splash/img/dark-3x.png 3x" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
    <img class="center" src="splash/img/light-1x.png" />
  </picture>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here my Console Error

at new firebase_messaging_web.FirebaseMessagingWeb.new (http://localhost:64821/packages/firebase_messaging_web/firebase_messaging_web.dart.lib.js:171:51)
at Function.registerWith (http://localhost:64821/packages/firebase_messaging_web/firebase_messaging_web.dart.lib.js:62:73)
at Object.registerPlugins (http://localhost:64821/packages/order_system/generated_plugin_registrant.dart.lib.js:32:49)
at main (http://localhost:64821/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:44:35)
at main.next ()
at runBody (http://localhost:64821/dart_sdk.js:39051:34)
at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:64821/dart_sdk.js:39082:7)
at main$ (http://localhost:64821/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:43:18)
at http://localhost:64821/main_module.bootstrap.js:19:10
at Array.forEach ()
at window.$dartRunMain (http://localhost:64821/main_module.bootstrap.js:18:32)
at :1:8
at Object.runMain (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:8656:21)
at http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22068:19
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3830:15)
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:10905:12)
at Object._asyncStartSync (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3794:20)
at main__closure1.$call$body$main__closure (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22080:16)
at main__closure1.call$1 (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22007:19)
at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary [as call$2$5] (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4153:16)
at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12136:39)
at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12068:14)
at _ControllerSubscription._sendData$1 (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11697:19)
at _DelayedData.perform$1 (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11849:59)
at _PendingEvents_schedule_closure.call$0 (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11898:14)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3990:24)
at StaticClosure._startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3996:11)
at _AsyncRun__initializeScheduleImmediate_internalCallback.call$1 (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:10774:9)
at invokeClosure (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1250:26)
at MutationObserver. (http://localhost:64821/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1269:18)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try replacing:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.5/fire-messaging.js"></script>
```

with:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

I am not sure that fire-messaging.js actually exists